# Can we bind one combobox to multiple value members?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to display column 1 and column2 of two different SQL tables In single combobox vertically. In my case it is showing y table col3 but not showing x table col 1 in combobox. Is it possible to assisgn multiple value members to single combobox or not ?

```
this code is just to explain you how I am trying.

                    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "x table col1"
                    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "y table col3"
```

Comment: Check the following. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp
Does this look like your join?

Comment: I am trying to bind same combobox to two different datatable columns and it is showing only one datatable column

Comment: @pankajbabbar It sounds like you want to concatenate the columns in Sql try `SELECT COL1 + ' '  COL2 ...` or a `UNION` of the two tables. If you include some sample data and a demonstration of the output, we can be more specific in our answers

Comment: I want to ask that can we bind multiple Value members to single combobox?

Comment: No you can not. Instead you can combine values of two tables into one collection and use it as DataSource for ComboBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used 2 select strings with 2 commands (a single connection assuming they are both in the same database). Both readers add their data to the same list which is the data source for the combo box.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim s = "Select col1  From TableX;"
    Dim lst As New List(Of String)
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.CoffeeConnection)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(s, cn)
            cn.Open()
            Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While reader.Read
                    lst.Add(reader.GetString(0))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
        s = "Select col3 From TableY"
        Using cmd2 As New SqlCommand(s, cn)
            Using reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                While reader.Read
                    lst.Add(reader.GetString(0))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    ComboBox1.DataSource = lst
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
Do you mean something like this?

```
Dim s = "Select col1, col2 From TableX"
```

Then the addition to the list would look like this.

```
lst.Add($"{reader.GetString(0)}, {reader.GetString(1)}")
```

Comment: your code is working fine. what if i want to add one more column in lst and bound to another combobox like combobox value member and display member.

Comment: See the EDIT to my answer. I used an interpolated string which is available in Visual Studio 2015 and later. If this is not what you mean, please clarify.

Comment: actually i want to add col1 value to combobox1 and col2 value to combobox2 and when i select col1 value col2 value should be automatically selected  as we do in combobox value member and combobox display member.